# How can I automatically execute normal mode keystrokes with a terminal command when opening Vim?

Tags: invocation

How do I run vim with file.txt and **screen center** at line 100?
Basically I would like to use `zz` mapping when starting Vim.

This does not work: `vim -c "zz" file.txt +100`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zz` is a normal mode command, so use `:normal`:

```
vim "+normal zz" file.txt +100
vim -c "normal zz" file.txt +100
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to run multiple commands in one line

```
vim README.md +"56;norm zz"
```